# argument of type "char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCWSTR"

Tags: c++, winapi, char, intellisense, lpcwstr

I get this error:

> argument of type "char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCWSTR"

Here's a part of my code

```
void score(void)
{
    char s[128];
    sprintf_s(s, "Thread War! Hits:%d  Misses:%d", hit, miss);
    SetConsoleTitle(s);
    ...
}
```

How to fix this?

Comment: I would guess that your compiler settings are set to Unicode, so the winapi functions will be unicode versions taking wide characters. [SetConsoleTitle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686050(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: The `W` in `LPCWSTR` indicates the function actually wants a `wchar_t*` instead of a `char*`. Hungarian type notation is ugly, but well clear at least if used consistently.

Comment: I understand that he wants a `wchar_t*` instead of `char*`, but if i write `wchar_t s[128]` I'll get the error with `sprintf_s`

Comment: @Mockingbird That is why there is `swprintf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're building with the `UNICODE` macro defined, which means that all functions default to their wide-character equivalent. So when you call `SetConsoleTitle` that's really a macro that expands to `SetConsoleTitleW`.

A wide character has the type `wchar_t` and is incompatible with `char`.

You either have to explicitly call `SetConsoleTitleA`, remove the definition of `UNICODE`, or start using `TCHAR` and related types and macros.